# How to use a java 8 library with android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a library that uses java 8 in my android project. I cannot find a way to make this work. I've tried to use retro lambda but it has not helped. I keep getting the error: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version(0034.0000)

I've researched this and learned it's because there is java 8 syntax in the included library. I've been compiling with java 8 sdk and am using android studio 08.2. Help!
The library is:https://github.com/robrua/Orianna

Comment: There's no way to recompile the library using Java 7? Should be the way probably

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1

Wait for android to support Java8.

### Solution 2

Use an earlier version of the library that isn't Java8 and/or ask the developer of the library to provide one/ the last Java6 (or Java7 for kitcat upwards) library.

### Solution 3

**This is some kind of hack** and I haven't tested or even used it!

Use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) to backport the Java8-bytecode to Java6. On the homepage of retrolambda you find some documentation about it.
Downloads of retrolambda are [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/net/orfjackal/retrolambda/retrolambda/1.1.2/).

Probably you will have to unzip the library jar to a folder and the run a command like the following:

```
java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=<extracted_classfiles>
     -Dretrolambda.classpath=<extracted_classfiles>
     -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=50
     -javaagent:retrolambda.jar
     -jar retrolambda.jar
```

Maybe you have to extend the classpath depending on the dependencies of the library.
Then you have to copy the resulting jar-file into your android-project's lib folder.

It is also possible to [program Java8 for android](http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html).

If retrolambda doesn't work maybe you can find another tool to backport Java8-bytecode to Java6-bytecode.

Comment: considering it's android, retroweaving to java-6 could be a good plan too after using retrolambda to java-7

Comment: @Zhuinden Retrolambda is able to backport Java8 to Java5, 6 and 7. In fact the code I've given backports to Java6 (Majorversion=50) and not to Java7 (Majorversion=51). Corrected it in my post.

Comment: @AlexS But what if the library uses other Java 8 features (not only lambda) ?

Comment: I have the same question as @hzitoun. For example Base64 encoder came in java util as part of java 8. Will that be supported.