# Java 8 and Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on a project split in 2: the library for the network stuff, written in pure Java (so it can be reused for a desktop version), and the Android app that only contains the GUI.

The Android app's Gradle build imports the java library.

I'm new to Android but I'm experienced in Java 8.

This page on the official documentation says that Streams are only available in Android level 24 of higher, but the project management would like the level to be 22 (Android 5.1). I understand that I won't be able to use Streams in the Android app then.

Does that mean I cannot use Streams in the Java library too though? Since the library is not written in Android but in regular Java, and that Gradle links them through bytecode, can I write the library using Streams & Java 8, then import it in the Android project?

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795161/how-to-use-a-java-8-library-with-android) you can't do that. But you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) in your library.

More onto retrocompatibility in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: Does retrolambda work on the dependencies or on the project itself? Like, do I apply retrolambda on the lib the add it, or write the app & the API in J8 then apply retrolambda to both

Comment: Also, it's unclear whether retrolambda only works on lambda-expressions or whether it also works for Streams, Optionals,...